# Trying to execute the following command shell_exec("sudo /usr/bin/nmap -n -sn ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) but it returns NULL

Tags: php, linux, nginx, shell-exec, nmap

I'm running

- nginx 1.17.4
- php 7.4
- arch linux 5.4.2

Trying to execute the following command to get my user MAC address from IP (this script will run on my lan server) and $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] does return a valid ip

```
shell_exec("sudo /usr/bin/nmap -n -sn ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
```

But it returns null so I tried the following to get a more info

```
shell_exec("sudo /usr/bin/nmap -n -sn ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ." 2>&1")
```

And got the following: **sudo: effective uid is not 0, is sudo installed setuid root?**

I don't understand why I get this error because I have added the following in my sudder file

```
http ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/nmap
```

I've modified my passwd to allow login from HTTP to try it in shell and it works but not when I run it in the browser.

Help please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since my server is arch linux I decide to go ask in that arch forum and found was able to fix my issue. so for anybody interested please view

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1877560#p1877560

Basically for me it was changing the php-fpm service file to the following

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/php-fpm.service

Set NoNewPrivileges=false

comment CapabilityBoundingSet
```